# Is there a meaningful difference between these two usages of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas and I have come up with two different ways of doing something:

```py
import pandas as pd

def csv_parser(path):
    a = pd.read_csv(path)
    
    return a

teeburu = csv_parser(R"H:\Documents\Coding\Project\Tables\1 - Overall Type Table.csv")

print(type(teeburu.iloc[0,1]))
print(type(teeburu.iloc[0,0]))
```

and:

```py
import pandas as pd

def csv_parser(path):
    a = pd.read_csv(path)
    
    return a

teeburu = csv_parser(R"H:\Documents\Coding\Project\Tables\1 - Overall Type Table.csv")

teeburu_df = pd.DataFrame(data=teeburu)

print(type(teeburu_df.iloc[0,1]))
print(type(teeburu_df.iloc[0,0]))
```

What I wanna know is if there's any meaningful difference between the two, and if I'm not using the `pd.DataFrame` function, it will still store the table internally.

Comment: In the latter case, you have *two different dataframe objects*. That's the difference.

Comment: "and if I'm not using the pd.DataFrame function, it will still store the table internally." I'm not sure what that means

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` returns a DataFrame, so `teeburu_df = pd.DataFrame(data=teeburu)` is redundant - `teeburu` is already a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is and you should use the first one.

The second one creates a new dataframe object, located in a different memory address (you can check this with the `id` function) but with the same underlying data.

This means that if you change some data in the first dataframe with `inplace` (which you should't use but whatever) it will change in the second one too.

Example

```py
import pandas as pd

def csv_parser(path):
    a = pd.read_csv(path)

    return a

teeburu_df1 = csv_parser('data.csv')
teeburu_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=teeburu_df1)

print('Before')
print(teeburu_df2)

teeburu_df1.fillna(1, inplace=True)

print('\nAfter')
# After changing first dataframe with inplace, second one changes
print(teeburu_df2)


print('\nId of first df', id(teeburu_df1))  # Prints different id than below
print('Id of second df', id(teeburu_df2))  # Prints different id than above
```

prints

```
Before
      A   B
0   NaN NaN
1  19.0 NaN

After
      A    B
0   1.0  1.0
1  19.0  1.0

Id of first df 139865179561408
Id of second df 139866333609936
```

csv:

```
A,B
,
19,
```